# "VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file '(VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)."

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

When I try to open Kali Linux in VirtualBox I get this error:

```
Could not open the medium 'C:\Users\aboza\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa2576.18979\kali-linux-2023.2-virtualbox-amd64.vdi'.
VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'C:\Users\aboza\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa2576.18979\kali-linux-2023.2-virtualbox-amd64.vdi' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).
Result Code:
E_FAIL (0X80004005)
Component:
MediumWrap
Interface:
IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
```

Comment: Your file `kali-linux-2023.2-virtualbox-amd64.vdi` is missing. If you don't know why, create a new VM.